# How to sum multiple rows based on the id filter criteria?

Tags: sum, aggregate-functions, sybase, dbeaver

I have table with `record_id` and `record_value`. Query should return all id's and values but at the same time I need to return sum for specific group of id's. Here is example of my data:

```
record_id    record_value   
54               3
56               0
78               11
98               7
103              1
78               0
44               0
67               1
68               3
69               1
```

Query that I have returns rows with id's and values. I would like to get some of these columns as well in query result. Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT 
    record_id, 
    record_value 

    CASE 
        WHEN record_id IN ('54','56','67','68','69') THEN SUM(record_value) 
        ELSE ''
    END AS RowSum
FROM Records
```

RowSum should return `19` but instead I'm getting an error:

```
SQL Error [257] [37000]: Implicit conversion from datatype 'VARCHAR' to 'NUMERIC' is not allowed.  Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
```

I use `Sybase` database with `DBeaver`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't use multiple results in one query. You can try with an *UNION ALL*
2. If you use CASE then both WHERE clauses should have the same type. You have used a NUMERIC (for SUM) an VARCHAR (for empty string ''). You need to unify them.

The code you might use is:

```
SELECT 
    record_id, 
    record_value, 
FROM Records
union all
select null,
    CASE 
        WHEN record_id IN ('54','56','67','68','69') THEN convert(varchar, SUM(record_value)) 
        ELSE ''
    END AS RowSum
```